# The line through $(3, 4, -1)$ normal to $x+4y-z=-2$ intersects a coordinate axis, or not?

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

Does the Line passing through $(3, 4, -1)$ and which is normal to $x+4y-z=-2$, intersect any of the coordinate axes?

So I have found the parametric equations of this line which are:

\begin{align}x&=3+t\\ y&=4+4t\\ z&=-1-t\end{align}

Do I set these equations to zero to find if they intersect the coordinate axes? That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Hint: if it intersects say, $x$-axis then the $y$ and $z$ coords. must be zero.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: so how would I solve this? just through trial and error?

Comment: If by "trial and error" you mean substitution $y=z=0$, then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{cases}x=3+t\\ y=4+4t\\ z=-1-t\end{cases}$$

Along each of the coordinate axes, at least two of $x,y,z$ must be $0$. So try out the three different cases $(x,0,0),(0,y,0),(0,0,z)$ and see if there is a consistent result(s) to the system in each.

Comment: You don't have to do casework, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your parametrization can be written in the form:

\begin{align} x
 &= (t+1)+2\\ y &= 4(t+1)\\ z &= -(t+1)
\end{align}

Note that $y(t) = \lambda z(t)$ for some scalar, while $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ or $x(t)$ and $z(t)$ do not differ only by scalar, but by a non-zero constant as well. This means that $y$ and $z$ can be simultaneously $0$, while $x$ and $y$ or $y$ and $z$ cannot.

Thus, set $y = z = 0$ and solve system

\begin{align}4(t+1)&=0\\ -(t+1) &= 0\end{align}

to get $t = -1$. Substitute it back to get $x = 2$. Thus, your line passes through point $(2,0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

for the $yz$ axis must $$y=z=0$$ and we get $t=-1$ therefore our intersection point is given by $S(2;0;0)$

Comment: the answer should be at (2, 0, 0)

Comment: how shuld it be?

Comment: because thats the answer in the book

Comment: ok i will correct it

Comment: And $(2,0,0)$ happens to be correct. You are confusing coordinate axis with $yz$ plane.

Comment: @Ennar can you take me through how you got that?

Comment: yes i have coreected my mistake, sorry